# Business Finance

Tags: finance

I have a huge problem in solving this Question.
Q: Multinational group of companies has taken loan from Bank in 2015 which they have to  repay in year 2022 @ 14% interest rate on biannual compounding. The amount due in 2022 is 1,500,000. Calculate the amount loan taken by Multinational Group in 2015 and the total amount of interest they have to pay to bank during loan period.
Plz help me asap.

Comment: Hint: questions including "asap" are automatically ignored by many people.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good. As this question appears to be homework, please consider reading [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1803/8348) for information about asking _effective_ homework-related questions. Cheers!

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1500000%3D+A*(1%2B.14*2)%5E14

Answer (score 0):

Let be $L$ the loan at $t=2015$ and $S=1,500,00$ the amount at $t=2022$, that is after $n=7$ years, and $i^{(1/2)}=14\%$ the interest compounded biannually.

We have
$$
L=\frac{S}{\left(1+\frac{i^{(1/2)}}{1/2}\right)^{n/2}}=\frac{1,500,00}{\left(1.28\right)^{7/2}}\approx 632,203
$$